# Collapsable div but only on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a collapse/expand toggle button only shown on mobile (using bootstrap) but Id also like the div to be collapsed by default on mobile.
I'm looking for the option to collapse the messages div only on mobile (where it is collapsed by default)

Any way to get a `div` to be collapsed on mobile but expanded on desktop viewing?

```
<a class="btn btn-primary hidden-lg hidden-md" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#messages">Recent Messages <i class="icon-caret-down"></i></a>

<div id="messages" class="collapse in">
<h5>My Messages ... </h5></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should probably use .visible-sm or .visible-xs on your button instead of .hidden-lg .hidden-md, because there are still two more sizes up (xl and xxl).

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Secondly, the bootstrap collapse just toggles on and off the CSS property display: none. So set display to none by default, then turn it to block for medium and up screens.

So following the principle of mobile first:

```
#messages {
    display: none;    
}

@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    #messages {
        display: block;    
    }
}
```

If you're not using LESS, the variable @screen-md-min should be changed to 992px.

Comment: I think this is the right direction but one issue is that after pressing the button to toggle the collapsed state my own css is not being overwritten by bootstraps to change `display:none` to `display:block`